# Angular $parser won't work in attribute directive with input template

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I really need to leave it as a attribute, company rules.

Here is the jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/M3sZN/

I can't seem to get the console.logs to work for $parser when I type into the input box.

```
var module = angular.module("demo", []);

module.directive('lowercase', function() {
    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            ngModel: '='
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attr, ngModelCntrl) {
            ngModelCntrl.$formatters.unshift(function (text) {
                 console.log('from formatters: ');
            });
            ngModelCntrl.$parsers.push(function (text) {
                console.log('from parsers: ');
            });


        },
        template: '<input ng-model="ngModel" type="text">',
    };
});

function Demo($scope) {
    $scope.data = 'Some Value';
}
```

And here is the HTML:

```
<div ng-app="demo" ng-init="" ng-controller="Demo">
    <div lowercase ng-model="data"></div>    
</div>
```

I have tried a lot but this includes the following:

- Using `require: '^ngModel',` instead.
- Removing the scope, though I need it for the rest of the directive I'm using.
- Changing up the names to use myModel to pass in the model.
- And a lot of other things that I have lost track of.

### Edit

I was able to get this working like this: http://jsfiddle.net/M3sZN/2/

#### HTML:

```
<div ng-app="demo" ng-init="" ng-controller="Demo">
    <input lowercase ng-model="data" type="text">    
</div>
```

#### JS

```
var module = angular.module("demo", []);

module.directive('lowercase', function() {
    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attr, ngModelCtr) {
            ngModelCtr.$formatters.unshift(function (text) {
                 console.log('from formatters: ');
            });
            ngModelCtr.$parsers.push(function (text) {
                console.log('from parsers: ' + text);
                return text;
            });
        }
    };
});

module.controller('Demo', Demo);

function Demo($scope) {
    $scope.data = 'Some Value';
}
```

By removing the template and just putting the model directly onto the input field.

This is NOT ideal, since I would like to use a template since I have a ton of attributes that need to go on the input field. I would like to avoid the duplication each time I use this directive.